# Consulta a fecha de mi Base de Datos y mi fecha actual

Tags: python, django, date, datetime

Mi problema es el siguiente: Estoy ocupando un campo de una de mis tablas `PlannedStartDateTime` el cual tiene una hora de comienzo y hay otro con la hora final, solo me interesa la hora de comienzo (el campo antes mencionado), de acuerdo con la fecha de hoy solo me filtre las del día de hoy sin importar la hora, ya que en mi base de datos son tipo `datatime2`.

Mi código:

```
                    dateNow = datetime.now()
                    hora = dateNow.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
                    fecha = dateNow.strftime("%Y:%m:%d")
                    timeJob = sJob.objects.filter(Q(RealStartDateTime__lte=dateNow),Q(RealEndDateTime__gte=dateNow)).values('id')
                    #ES ESTE  "timePlanned"
                    timePlanned = sJobPlanned.objects.filter(Q(PlannedStartDateTime=dateNow)).values('PlannedStartDateTime')
```

Lo que esa linea me realiza es traerme las fechas de HOY pero que aún no pasan (por la hora), por ejemplo: si son las 9 AM y tengo un registro de HOY pero esta a las 3 PM, si me lo muestra, pero si quiero ya paso... al momento de imprimirlo ya no me aparece, cuando yo quiero que TODOS los registros de HOY sin importar la hora me los muestre.

Ya intente varias alternativas y me pasa lo mismo.
¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0):

Si no entendí mal tu explicación, el siguiente truco debería funcionar.

Se trata de poner a 0 la hora, minutos y segundos del objeto `dateNow`, pues de ese modo todos los eventos de ese día, sin importar la hora, serán "futuros" con respecto a ese `dateNow`, y así te devolvería todos ellos.

Se haría así:

```
dateNow = datetime.now().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
# ...
timePlanned = sJobPlanned.objects.filter(Q(PlannedStartDateTime=dateNow)).values('PlannedStartDateTime')
```

Comment: Me bota vacío en mi consola, sigue sin agarrar.

Comment: Entonces quizás no entendí bien. Lo que hace mi código es poner como fecha la de hoy, pero a las cero horas. ¿No debería entonces mostrarte los eventos de ese día pero con hora posterior? Igual entendí mal y era con hora anterior... En ese caso en vez de usar 0 para `hour`, `minute` y `second` puedes usar 23, 59 y 59 respectivamente. Así te pones "al final de hoy". Y si tampoco te funciona entonces es que tal vez el filtro no funciona como has descrito

Comment: Igual me arroja vació, bueno; debo de filtrar todos los productos que se realizan en el día de HOY pero cada producto empieza en horas diferentes pero todos son del día de HOY, entonces, lo que mi consulta me arroja es : los productos de HOY que aún no han pasado (por ejemplo ya son las 2:20 y solo me arroja los que AUN NO han pasaso su hora)cuando yo quiero los productos que se empezaron a las 7, 8,9,etc.. AM también, o sea, quiero que me arroje TODA la productividad del día de hoy sin importar la hora que sea. ¿me explico?

Comment: Sí, pero si dices que al pasarles un objeto `datetime` que contenga fecha y hora, solo te muestra los de ese día que aún no han pasado por esa hora, entonces si la consulta la hicieras a las 00:00 te mostraría todos los del día, no? Esa es la "trampa" que intenté hacer, al poner esa hora en el objeto `datetime`. Quizás es que la base de datos ignora la hora que le pasas en ese objeto y tiene su propia forma de saber qué hora es.

Comment: Si, así es, en teoría debería de arrojarlas, pero me los muestra como vacíos...igual es lo que estaba pensando que de algún lugar la reconoce, pero no se de donde.

Answer (score 0):

Esto es muy sencillo de realizar en Django. Antes que nada observa esto:

```
>>> from import datetime, time
>>> today = datetime.now()
>>> today
datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 14, 13, 44, 56, 944371)
>>> datetime.combine(today, time.min)
datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 14, 0, 0)
>>> datetime.combine(today, time.max)
datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 14, 23, 59, 59, 999999)
```

Haciendo uso de [`datetime.combine`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine), puedes usar tu variable `dateNow` y transformarla de tal forma que tengas un rango entre el inicio y el final de ese día (usando [`datetime.time.min`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.time.min) y [`datetime.time.max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.time.max), que corresponden al mínimo y máximo tiempo representable en Python).

Por lo tanto, tu consulta en Django debería ser:

```
from datetime import datetime, time

# ...
dateNow = datetime.now()
dateNow_min = datetime.combine(dateNow, time.min)
dateNow_max = datetime.combine(dateNow, time.max)
timePlanned = sJobPlanned.objects.filter(PlannedStartDateTime__range=(dateNow_min, dateNow_max)).values('PlannedStartDateTime')
```

Ojo, no es necesario usar el objeto `Q` en este caso. Usarla en una sola expresión no tiene sentido.

Comment: Me arroja un solo registro (que aun no ha pasado) de igual manera.
Pero, lo puse solucionar de otra forma, sacando año, mes y día individualmente y colocando las variables en mi consulta. 
___________________________________________________________________________________

timePlanned = sJobPlanned.objects.filter(Q(PlannedStartDateTime__year=year),Q(PlannedStartDateTime__month=mes),Q(PlannedStartDateTime__day=dia)).values('id','PlannedQuantity','PlannedStartDateTime','PlannedEndDateTime')